What are the differences between job_start() and system()?
They both run external processes in a non-blocking way, but so far as I know, system() is used to capture the output from the shell whereas job_start() is used when you want to deal with callback functions based on what the running job is doing. Other than that, they look equivalent to me.
Is there any additional nuances that I am missing?


They both run external processes in a non-blocking way

system() is blocking.
Starting from the lowest-level…
:!cmd
:[range]!sleep 5

will prevent anything you do (except <C-c>, basically) to have any effect for 5 seconds.
Additionally, the output, if any, is printed in the parent shell if you don't specify a range or used to replace the specified range.
system()
:call system('sleep 5')

will also block the UI for 5 seconds but the commands you issue during that time are buffered and will be executed as soon as possible.
There is no switch to the parent shell anymore, which is smoother, and you get the ability to assign the output to a variable:
:let foo = system('whatever')

or use it as part of an expression:
:%s/foo/\=system('whatever ' .. \0)/g

which is pretty powerful.
job_start()
:let bat = job_start('sleep 5')

is fully asynchronous: you can keep editing your buffer, changing windows, etc. while the external command runs.
You get all the benefits of system(), plus:

no blocking whatsoever,
external command is executed directly, without a shell,
external command can be controlled programmatically.

So what you have here, really, is a scale of increasing sophistication that corresponds theoretically to the sophistication of your needs.
